# Bastionhost configuration with NaviServer on GCP?

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, webserver

How to add TLS/SSL letsencrypt or GCP provided certificate to VM instance in GCP with an internal ip address and static external address?

When I create one via a letsencrpt certificate install script, resultant connections break because the VM doesn't have an external facing ip number --only an internal number.

The traffic  passes through a firewall (or load balancer) of sorts.

I'm used to bastionhost VM servers in the wild..

Details: NaviServer web server is running on a GCP Compute Engine with a FreeBSD 11.3 image.

(Linux Shield OSes aren't letting me compile Naviserver and use it on any port).

All works for port 80 and 8000 on an internal ip address, and a static ip address pointed externally and not connected to the VM.

I can't find any proxy/firewall settings to navigate via GCP menus.

How to resolve?

Is there some special term I should use to search for docs?

Any link with instructions to follow?

Is there a way to expose a VM instance directly to an external ip address?

Any other creative way I may get SSL/TLS to work with NaviServer?

thank you

Links to some things I've tried:

[Enable SSL on Tomcat on Google Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403299/enable-ssl-on-tomcat-on-google-compute-engine)

[How to setup Letsencrypt for Google Cloud Compute Engine load balancer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47337817/how-to-setup-letsencrypt-for-google-cloud-compute-engine-load-balancer)  <-- this is for Kubernetes clusters

I'm currently trying adding a load balancer:
https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs

Comment: If you do not have an external IP address responding to port 80, you will need to use the DNS-01 verification method. https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/

Comment: Thank you, @John Hanley. The server responds on port 80 via the external IP number, where the traffic is forwarded to an internal IP number.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the solution: Use a GCP HTTP/S load balancer: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https
and specifically:
https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-https-lb-simple

Argh. Actually No.

GCP Team kindly suggested this url: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/custom-hostname-vm#create-custom-hostname
Set the hostname to the domain name. Treat this as if there's no proxy, just a firewall.